# Will travis build matrix lead to multiple deploys?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm using Travis [build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build) to run tests in Node 6 (stable) and latest. Then Travis will [deploy to node](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/).

But at the end of the logs for both Node 6 and latest, I see the following lines:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
Preparing deploy
Deploying application
```

Does that mean that Travis tries to deploy the app two times to NPM?
How would I know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that both the builds in your Travis build matrix are using the same version of your source code and `package.json`, the second attempt to publish to NPM will result in an error as it will be a duplicate version.

[NPM specifies that](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) `npm publish` will fail "if the package name and version combination already exists in the specified registry".

However, as this is in the deploy section, Travis will probably ignore the second error and finish the process. I'm not sure whether it will show that error in the log.

If you wish, you can [specify a conditional release using the `on:` statement](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A) inside your deploy section. e.g. by setting it to:

```
deploy:
  provider: npm
  on:
    node: latest
```